# Why does the border stop rendering its minus margin while resizing the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, border

I've used a border with negativ margin to mark a grid row. But I get a strange behaviour while resizing the window. Cutting the second column of the row makes the margin of the border disappear:

[image: Lost borderbackground]

Of course this is a small example, in the main application I'm using a grid splitter, but the bahaviour stays the same. Is it possible to fix this somehow or is it a WPF bug?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestHighlightBorder.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestHighlightBorder"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid Margin="100,0,0,0" >

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="DarkRed" Opacity="0.3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="-80,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="column 0" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="column 2" Background="LightGreen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

</Grid>
```

ps:
This is how the main application looks like. It's some sort of a propertygrid. The amount of the negativ margin depends on the level of nested objects.
[image: main app]

Comment: Why don't you remove the negative margin from the border, and use a positive one ahead of the `TextBlock`?

Comment: As a fix I would assume that removing the margins and just adding 2 columns to the `Grid` (20 and 80) and having the Border start in the second column should work. But out of interest, could you test what happens if you give the border a `ColumnSpan` of `2`?

Comment: In the main application I'm using multiple nested rows, which are dynamically generated, thus the margin also varrieds. tl;dr I need the negativ margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example and it happens just as you said: column 2 gone, margin gone.
This seems to happen whenever the grid can't be displayed completely.
If, for example you set the third column definition to 200, the margin disappears as soon as column 2 isn't shown in it's entirety. Same thing happens when you resize the window from the bottom.

If you put the existing grid in another container (Grid, StackPanel, etc.) and set the MinWidth to something at least the size of the width of the columns + margin (in your example 310), this doesn't happen.

Like so:

```
<StackPanel MinWidth="310">
    <Grid Margin="100,0,0,0" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Background="DarkRed" Opacity="0.3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="-80,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <TextBlock Text="column 0" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Text="column 2" Background="LightGreen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a 100 left-margin to the grid, you could just fix a column at the beginning with the width of 100, set the column-span of the border to 4, replace the negative margin with 20 positive left-margin (100-80=20), and add 1 to the value of `Grid.Column` for each of your controls. So the final approach would look like that:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="DarkRed" Opacity="0.3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="20,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="column 0" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="column 2" Background="LightGreen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

</Grid>
```